# Why are Python threads that are launched in a Windows Service closing after 3 - 4 minutes?

Tags: python, multithreading, windows-services

I'm new to asking questions on the site but have used Stackoverflow for looking up issues that other users have had for the past couple of years.  Unfortunately I couldn't find a post here related to the issue I have now.  So here goes...

I have a Python script that I want to run immediately during boot (i.e even during the Windows login screen).  To do this, I'm creating a Windows service using the Python win32serviceutil framework and will set the service to "auto" when the service is installed.  It seems pretty straightforward and I got a service working pretty quickly by looking at examples posted on the web.  My code looks as follows:

```
import win32service
import win32serviceutil
import win32api
import win32con
import win32event
import win32evtlogutil
import os, sys, string, time
from STEL.ClientServer.StartClient import StartClient

class aservice(win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework):

   _svc_name_ = "STELClient"
   _svc_display_name_ = "My Service Long Fancy Name!"
   _svc_description_ = "THis is what my crazy little service does - aka a DESCRIPTION! WHoa!"

   def __init__(self, args):
       win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework.__init__(self, args)
       self.hWaitStop = win32event.CreateEvent(None, 0, 0, None)
       self.client = StartClient()

   def SvcStop(self):
       self.ReportServiceStatus(win32service.SERVICE_STOP_PENDING)
       win32event.SetEvent(self.hWaitStop)

   def SvcDoRun(self):
      import servicemanager
      servicemanager.LogMsg(servicemanager.EVENTLOG_INFORMATION_TYPE,servicemanager.PYS_SERVICE_STARTED,(self._svc_name_, ''))

      self.timeout = 10000    
      # This is how long the service will wait to run / refresh itself (see script below)
      try:
          self.client.startClient()
      except:
          servicemanager.LogInfoMsg("STELClient - EXCEPTION !!")  #For Event Log

      while 1:
         # Wait for service stop signal, if I timeout, loop again
         rc = win32event.WaitForSingleObject(self.hWaitStop, self.timeout)
         # Check to see if self.hWaitStop happened
         if rc == win32event.WAIT_OBJECT_0:
            # Stop signal encountered
            self.client.stopClient()
            servicemanager.LogInfoMsg("STELClient - STOPPED!")  #For Event Log
            break
         else:
            execfile("C:\\STEL\\clientExample.py")
            pass


def ctrlHandler(ctrlType):
   return True

if __name__ == '__main__':
   win32api.SetConsoleCtrlHandler(ctrlHandler, True)
   win32serviceutil.HandleCommandLine(aservice)
```

The main code of interest is:

```
try:
      self.client.startClient()
  except:
      servicemanager.LogInfoMsg("STELClient - EXCEPTION !!")  #For Event Log
```

and:

```
else:
    execfile("C:\\STEL\\clientExample.py")
    pass
```

Both blocks of code ping the same server.  The only difference is that the clientExample.py pings the server once whenever the script is called.  In this case, it is pinged every 10 seconds due to the while loop.  client.startClient() spawns its own thread and pings the server every 5 seconds.

After I install the service and then run the script, I notice that the client.startClient() thread seems to get stopped after 3-4 minutes (roughly 3 minutes and 40 seconds when I timed it) but the clientExample.py continues to run every 10 seconds.

If I were to run the following lines of code in Python, the thread runs indefinitely until I stop/close Python.

```
from STEL.ClientServer.StartClient import StartClient
self.client = StartClient()
self.client.startClient()
```

I expected this same behavior in the Windows Service but that doesn't seem the case.

Does anyone have any clues?

Comment: Anyone have any clues on this?  Still really confused on why this is happening :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I figured out the problem after hooking up a debugger to the service using WINPDB.

The reason why the thread was stopping was because there was an uncaught exception (dun dun DUNNNNN).  The exception was caused by a print statement (really???) which threw an IOError: 9 (Bad file descriptor).  I did a bit of StackOverflow searching and found this...

[why am I getting IOError: (9, 'Bad file descriptor') error while making print statements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4230855/why-am-i-getting-ioerror-9-bad-file-descriptor-error-while-making-print-st)

I'm going to remove my print statements and see if that resolves my problems...

Live an learn...