# print: "IOError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor"

Tags: python

I understand why I am getting the "Bad file descriptor" error when printing with no console from this post: [why am I getting IOError: (9, 'Bad file descriptor') error while making print statements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4230855/why-am-i-getting-ioerror-9-bad-file-descriptor-error-while-making-print-st).

My question is, how can I detect if stdout is available? Can I simply do something like this:

```
if os.path.isfile(2):
   print "text"
```

Thanks

Comment: You could just wrap a `print` in a `try … except`, could you not?

Comment: Sure. I had thought of that. I know there are different schools of thought, but, I prefer to be explicit in my actions. That is, look for what except and catch exceptions when I am wrong.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[os.path.isfile()](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/os.path.html#os.path.isfile) takes a file path (a string), not a file descriptor (a number), so your solution will not work as you expect.

You can use [os.isatty()](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/os.html#os.isatty) instead:

```
if os.isatty(1):
    print "text"
```

`os.isatty()` will return `True` if its argument is an open file descriptor connected to a terminal.

(In passing, note that `stdout` is file descriptor `1`. `stderr` is file descriptor `2`).

Answer (score 0):

The above answer did not work for me. But perhaps this is a bug in Python 2.x:
https://bugs.python.org/issue706263

I am using 2.7. os.isatty(1) returns true always but print still raises an exception after 4k bytes. I am using pythonw.exe to run a script in the background.