# Windows service with Flask only run in DEBUG mode. Normal mode seem crash

Tags: python, flask, service, window

I want to install python script (use Flask) as Windows service.
I use simple code as below (in myservice.py) :

```
import win32serviceutil
import win32service
import win32event
import win32evtlogutil
import servicemanager
import socket
import time
import logging
from multiprocessing import Process
import traceback
import logging
from datetime import datetime,tzinfo,timedelta
from flask import Flask
import os
import sys
sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(__name__))

app = Flask(__name__)

class Zone(tzinfo):
    def __init__(self,offset,isdst,name):
        self.offset = offset
        self.isdst = isdst
        self.name = name
    def utcoffset(self, dt):
        return timedelta(hours=self.offset) + self.dst(dt)
    def dst(self, dt):
            return timedelta(hours=1) if self.isdst else timedelta(0)
    def tzname(self,dt):
         return self.name

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    logging.info('[GET] hello_world ...')
    KST = Zone(+9,False,'KST')
    now_time = datetime.now(KST).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z')
    return 'Hello, World! ' + now_time

logging.basicConfig(
    filename = 'c:\\Temp\\hello-service.log',
    level = logging.DEBUG, 
    format = '[helloflask] %(levelname)-7.7s %(message)s'
)

class HelloFlaskSvc (win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework):
    _svc_name_ = "AIHello"
    _svc_display_name_ = "AI Hello"

    def __init__(self, *args):
        win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework.__init__(self, *args)
        self.hWaitStop = win32event.CreateEvent(None,0,0,None)
        #socket.setdefaulttimeout(5)
        self.stop_requested = False

    def SvcStop(self):
        self.ReportServiceStatus(win32service.SERVICE_STOP_PENDING)
        #self.process.terminate()
        win32event.SetEvent(self.hWaitStop)
        self.ReportServiceStatus(win32service.SERVICE_STOPPED)
        logging.info('Stopped service ...')
        self.stop_requested = True

    def SvcDoRun(self):
        servicemanager.LogMsg(
            servicemanager.EVENTLOG_INFORMATION_TYPE,
            servicemanager.PYS_SERVICE_STARTED,
            (self._svc_name_,'')
        )
        logging.info('Before main')

        app.run()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    if len(sys.argv) == 1:
        servicemanager.Initialize()
        servicemanager.PrepareToHostSingle(HelloFlaskSvc)
        servicemanager.StartServiceCtrlDispatcher()
    else:
        win32serviceutil.HandleCommandLine(HelloFlaskSvc)
```

I can install this script by command : **python.exe myservice.py -install**, it show up in Services list, but when i try to start it say "**The AI Hello service on Local Computer started and then stopped. Some service stop automatically if they are not in use by other services or program**".

I checked Event Viewer log, it show **" The instance's SvcRun() method failed
.Error getting traceback - traceback.print_exception() failed %2: %3"**

I am using Python 3.6.4 , Flask 1.0.2, pywin32-224, on Windows 10 64bit.

This script can work in DEBUG mode by command: **python myservice.py debug**

Hope somebody can help me out, please

**Updated:** I switched to Python 2.7. It show the same error. But in Event Viewer log:

```
The instance's SvcRun() method failed 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32\lib\win32serviceutil.py", line 839, in SvcRun
    self.SvcDoRun()
  File "D:\MusFatAI\FlaskServiceWin32-master\FlaskServiceWin32-master\win32_service.py", line 73, in SvcDoRun
    app.run(debug=False)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 938, in run
    cli.show_server_banner(self.env, self.debug, self.name, False)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 629, in show_server_banner
    click.echo(message)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\click\utils.py", line 261, in echo
    file.flush()
IOError: (9, 'Bad file descriptor')
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [why am I getting IOError: (9, 'Bad file descriptor') error while making print statements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4230855/why-am-i-getting-ioerror-9-bad-file-descriptor-error-while-making-print-st)

Comment: Thank you. It worked. I guess the problem that it don't have console screen to print out, so have to print to file which solve this

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem and I fixed it by putting this line on top of the script:

```
sys.stdout = sys.stderr = open(os.devnull, 'w')
```